# How to check is an input is a float of not

Tags: python, if-statement, integer

I am currently working on some code to tell wether my users input is a float or integer but it doesn't seem to be working can anyone help?

```
 number = input ("Enter something:")
 if type(number) != int:  
      print("Isn't a whole number")
 else:
      print("is a whole number")
```

Comment: Change it to `if not type(number) is int`

Comment: @kuro: Won't `number` *always* be a string?  Don't you need to try to convert it using `int()` or `float()`?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat  I think that is true for python 3.x

Answer (score -1):

Use `is` for type checking, ie
`not type(a) is int`

Comment: You can also do `type(a) is not int`.